# »Anlieferung« vs »Lieferung«

Tags: meaning, difference, synonym

Was ist der Unterschied zwischen *Lieferung* und *Anlieferung*?

In welchen Situationen soll ich das eine und das andere benutzen?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grundlegend ist ein Synonym für die Anlieferung eine Lieferung. 
Im Sprachgebrauch ist mit der Lieferung häufig der gesamte Ablauf angesprochen. Praktisch der gesamte Versandweg vom Versender zum Empfänger. 
Bei der Anlieferung wird in dem Sinne meist vom "Zustellen" an den Empfänger gesprochen. Also der ANLieferung AN den Empfänger.
Soweit also Deckungsgleich mit dem Vorsprecher, was vielleicht noch Interessant ist, dass der Begriff der Anlieferung am häufigsten im Versand oder der Logisikabteilung von Firmen verwendet wird.

Comment: Vom Versender aus ist wohl eher von Auslieferung, als von Anlieferung die Rede.

Answer (score 5):

Zusätzlich zu `ammoQ`s und `TheC`s Antworten beschreibt Lieferung auch die Ware, die geliefert wird. Sätze wie

> Ist die Lieferung schon da?

oder

> Ich kriege heute eine Lieferung, deswegen kann ich jetzt nicht kommen.

trifft man auch an.

Comment: Stimmt vollkommen, +1

Answer (score 4):

Anlieferung beschreibt nach meinem Verständnis nur den letzten Teil der Lieferung, nämlich den, bei dem die Ware beim Empfänger ankommt.

Lieferung beschreibt den gesamten Weg vom Sender zum Empfänger, gegebenenfalls mit Wechsel des Logistikdienstleisters. Oft wird aber "Lieferung" auch als Synonym für "Anlieferung" verwendet.

Comment: *Anlieferung* can also be used like on a signpost to tell people where the item should be dropped. That doesn't work with *Lieferung*